# Замена символа в переменной

Tags: php

Всем привет

```
$a = "Маша";
//нужно заменить у $a все М на С, что бы на выходе было:
$a = "Cаша";
```

Гуглил, пробовал. Господа, просьба громко не смеяться, но не могу понять алгоритм работы preg_replace. Думаю что решается через это.

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать? та ли функция, и как с ней быть?

Comment: Функция та, но `str_replace` в данном случае логичнее, т.к делает минимум работы. Алгоритм работы простой: проходим по строке; ищем вхождение в нее подстроки (первый параметр); при нахождении - заменяем ее на второй параметр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$b = str_replace("М","C",$a);
```